# Accessing multi-dimensional array data within Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I hope your all well.

I currently have an array that is being passed to my Laravel Controller that looks like this:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#43
  #json: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#35
    #parameters: array:3 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Developer"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "Admin"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "Ops Matrix User"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I am just wondering how I would access the array inside my Laravel controller function.

My guess is like this: `$request[0]->name` But when I do this it only returns one of the names and not three. So the main question is how do I go through each of these and get the names out of the individual arrays?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

After realising that this is a json Array I have now done a `json_decode` on this value and it has come back with the following:

```
array:3 [
  0 => {#1246
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "Developer"
  }
  1 => {#1249
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "Ops Matrix Admin"
  }
  2 => {#1247
    +"id": 3
    +"name": "Ops Matrix User"
  }
]
```

But the question still stands how do I get all of the `name` values out of this array and ready to be used by Laravel?

Comment: use `foreach` loop

Comment: @IBRAHIMEZZAT Can I do that within a controller. I was under the impression I might not be able to do that for some reason.

Comment: of course, you can check my answer, hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach loop to itirate request. it will be something like:

```
foreach($request->all() as $key => $value) {
    // to dump array key and value
    dump($key, $value);
   
  //lets say i want to access name value
  foreach($value as $val){

      $name=$val['name'];
      dump($name) // it will display "Developer" "Admin" "Ops Matrix User"
 }
```

}

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you again. I feel like I am on the right track with what you have mentioned here. But how would I go about accessing the individual values within the array?

For example the ID, or the name.

Thank you very much for your help so for. Apologies for not knowing I could use a foreach loop in a controller. Seems silly why I thought that now I look back on it.

Thanks

Comment: no sorry needed, you are welcome any time , please check my edited answer. You can access the value inside the foreach as `$value['id']` and `$value['name']`

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to answer this. I am currently getting a dump of ```"[{"id":1,"name":"Developer"},{"id":3,"name":"Ops Matrix User"}]"```. With your new answer I am currently getting ```"Illegal string offset 'name'", "exception": ```.

Comment: in this case, you will need another foreach to enter your element value, check my re-edited answer :-)

Comment: That came back with a ```"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", "exception":``` I will have a look around for the solution.

Thanks again.

Comment: this exception means this is not an array , try put (array) in front of value like: `foreach((array) $value as $val)`

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have mentioned that this maybe because I am sending it from a vue component. I am sure there is a way to actually make it an array. Either that or I am going crazy.

Comment: I have updated the post with what ```json_decode``` came back with. Thanks for all your help.